# symbolic matrix with fixed elements

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am trying to create a symbolic matrix but I want to fix some of it elements to 0 in order to reduce the size of the problem. I also want to send all the values to be positive. I have tried this:

```
X   = sym ('x',[n,n]);
X = sym(X,'positive');
X=times(X,Xf);
```

where Xf is an nxn matrix with zeros where I want to have fixed values and ones where I want to have the variables in the matrix.

When I solve the problem using `fminunc` I get some negative values and I also have non zero values for the values I wanted to fix.

n in my case is 30 and solving it with `fmincon` was not possible

Comment: Could you give some insight on the kind of problem you are trying to solve? I do not quite understand why you want to use fminunc with a symbolic matrix.

Comment: I trying to optimize a matrix of variables such that the differences between its elements and some base matrix elements as well as the difference between the sum of its columns and rows and two base vectors is minimized.@LucaCiti

Answer (score 0):

After reading your answer to my question, I think you do not need to use symbolic variables. Assuming you want to minimize the *squared* difference, you can try the following:

```
    n = 30;
    sumc = (10:n+9)'; % example target sum along columns
    sumr = 15:n+14; % example target sum along rows
    Xtarget = magic(n);  % example target matrix
    Xf = fliplr(eye(n)); % example masking matrix
    X = zeros(n); % example matrix with constant values for masked inputs

    if 0 % easy test case
        X = Xtarget;
        sumc = sum(X, 2);
        sumr = sum(X, 1);
    end

    ix = find(Xf);
    cost = @(A) norm(A(:) - Xtarget(:)) + ...
                norm(sum(A,1) - sumr) + ...
                norm(sum(A,2) - sumc);

    x = fminunc(@(x) cost(subsasgn(X, substruct('()', {ix}), exp(x))), rand(length(ix), 1)); %#ok<SUBSASGN>
    X(ix) = exp(x);
```

Comment: Would you please explain how did you include the constraints of X>0 and  the elements that are forced to be zero in the matrix?

Comment: I did not force elements to be zero but to be an arbitrary constant (for example one). I edited the example so it's zero now.
Regarding the positiveness, one can try to use an exp function. See edited answer.